# How to disable range selection buttons?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock charts for stock charts. In my charts i have a buttons like 1D,5D, 6M, 3YR, 10YR and YTD.
When i resize the chart (ipad portrait mode), 3yr,10yr and YTD buttons are coming out of the chart.
there is no enough room for buttons in chart.So i need to disable few buttons and show only 1D,5D and YTD buttons in chart.

on desktop mode:
[image]

On ipad portrait mode:

[image]

Can you suggest me how to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

To disable the range selector, you can use this code:

```
rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
}
```

and to modify it's buttons, you can use this code;

```
rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
        type: 'day',
        count: 3,
        text: '3d'
     }, {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w'
     }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m'
     }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: '1y'
     }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
     }],
     selected: 3
}
```

Maybe less number of buttons can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use CSS to hide some of buttons, see: http://jsfiddle.net/wcqP9/

```
.highcharts-button {
    display: none;
}
```